# How to use include rules for Gitlab CI remote files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

The example [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#include-with-rulesif) shows that you can use include rules using if statements. I am familiar with referencing the external files. My question has to do with using a filter on which external files to include, based on the rule. For example, below is the filter and it should choose the external file to use based on the variable:

```
include:
  - project: 'repo/path/project1'
    ref: main
    file: 'pipeline/true.yml'
    rules:
      if: $MY_VARIABLE == "false"
  - project: 'repo/path/project2'
    ref: main
    file: 'pipeline/false.yml'
    rules:
      if: $MY_VARIABLE  == "true"
```

It looks like this may only work for locally referenced files, and not remote projects. Please let me know if anyone has found a solution or workaround for this (I do not want to include the pipelines in the same repo, or I would do that and then use the filter based on the local files)

Tried to reference external pipeline files and filter based on rules. The pipeline failed instead of passing and running the expected pipeline.

If this is the only thing in the pipeline, it errors out with the below messages:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vJzB.png]

But then if I add another job that just echoes a command, it will run only that command and ignore the external files.

Comment: Can you show a high level sctructure of your .gitlab-ci.yml file where this includes are (is it just the includes?) and also your true.yml and false.yml. what is the value of the MY_VARIABLE when you get this error. All this is needed to see what exactly is your final .gitlab-ci.yml file jobs looks like. The error could be due to a variety of root causes, so knowing all the inputs in your question will help nail down the correct root cause.

Comment: 1) ideally, this file would just be the includes
2) i am able to run the true.yml and false.yml from the .gitlab-ci.yml in their own pipeline, when not being referenced externally. this ensures that those files contain valid and successful pipelines

Comment: what is the version of gitlab?

Comment: does the user have the correct permissions on all the projects? Do the jobs show if you view the "merged YAML"?